# Correlation between every column in R

Tags: r, cycle, correlation

I have a data with 24 variables(columns) and 1000 rows. Columns represent **AGE,SALARY,REGION,GENDER**, etc.

I need to find correlation between each column, **(AGE,SALARY), (AGE, REGION) (AGE,GENDER)** etc.i.e. I need to gdet 23*24=552 correlations. Is there any way to make a cycle or something, and get all those correlations at once, rather than find it seperately 552 times?
Please help! I can't do it 552 times. There must be a way!

UPDATE: I think I got what I wanted by `COR<-cor(mytest[sapply(mytest,is.numeric)])`
and I got something like

```
    AGE      SALARY    REGION

AGE        1          NA       0.25
SALARY     NA          1
REGION     0.25        NA        1
```

etc. but now the problem is that it gives me NA's which I don't need. I tried this

```
> COR<-cor(mytest[sapply(mytest,is.numeric)],use="complete.obs")
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work, gives me error "no complete element pairs". How do I do that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want a correlation matrix, try this:

```
cor(yourdataframe)
```

EDIT:

I think I misunderstood, if you want to correlate Age with every other column try this:

```
apply(yourdataframe, 2, cor, x = AGE)
```

Comment: @MadinaTultabayeva I updated with what I think you're getting at. If I'm still wrong, maybe you should update with an example of your dataframe and the output you'd like to get.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want, find a correlation of every other column, not only AGE column though..like each column with every other column. Now it gives me error :"x has to be numeric"

Comment: @MadinaTultabayeva That's what the initial `cor(yourdataframe)` solution would provide, but it only works on numeric columns (since it's trying to calculate a correlation). Try this: `cor(yourdataframe[sapply(yourdataframe, is.numeric)])`

Comment: it worked, thank you. but it gives me NA's.. I updated the question. Do you know how to deal with them?

Answer (score -2):

you need to use select. try to refer to this link

http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/joe/exploring-column-correlation-and-cardinality-estimates/

Comment: You can add more description or give some example to understand it better and easy way rather that clicking on reference link.